# Installation ambari on centos7 when scp files

Tags: centos7, ambari

I'm installing Ambari 2.1.0:

- I can connect by ssh without pass (crossing id_rsa.pub)
- I checked HDP 2.3 with redhat7 OS
- Problem occurs in two hosts (phisical machines), one is local machine which is called master and another called worker1.
- File that show the error exists '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py'

when I confirm hosts it fails, it seems ssh connection was ok, but when is copying files fails:

```
==========================
Creating target directory...
==========================

Command start time 2016-04-23 19:38:19 


      sáb abr 23 19:38:19 CEST 2016  


Connection to master.cluster.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=master.cluster.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2016-04-23 19:38:19

==========================
Copying common functions script...
==========================

Command start time 2016-04-23 19:38:19

                          _              
scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons
host=master.cluster.com, exitcode=1
Command end time 2016-04-23 19:38:19

==========================
Copying OS type check script...
==========================

Command start time 2016-04-23 19:38:19

                          _              
scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py
host=master.cluster.com, exitcode=1
Command end time 2016-04-23 19:38:20

ERROR: Bootstrap of host master.cluster.com fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (1)
ERROR MESSAGE:                           _              

STDOUT: 
                          _
```

I have repeated the steps serveral times, but it will happen again. Please help

Comment: Ask here https://superuser.com or here https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Are the error message and stdout truly blank? Or did you remove their content for the posting?

Comment: Is blank, finnally I think i will connect with ambari-agent in each machine, I think is the simply way